# Angular 2 - multiple instance of service created

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have created AngularJS 2 service and use it in 2 differents components : App-Component & Sub-Component. Each one output property 'log' (a string) of my service.

**StateService class :**

```
@Injectable ()
class StateService {

    public log : string;
    static count : number = 0;

    constructor () {
        this.log = '';
        StateService.count++;
        this.writeToLog ('CREATED '+StateService.count+' at ' + new Date().toString());
    }

    public writeToLog (text : string) : void {
        this.log += text + '\n';
    }
}
```

**Component :**

```
@Component ({
    selector : 'Sub-Component',
    template : `<hr>
            This is the Sub-Component !
            <BR>
            StateService Log : 
            <pre>{{ _stateService.log }}</pre>
            <button (click)="WriteToLog ()">Write to log</button>
            `,
    providers : [StateService]
})

export class SubComponent {
    constructor (private _stateService : StateService) {
    }

    public WriteToLog () : void {
        this._stateService.writeToLog ('From Sub-Component - This is '+new Date().toString());
    }
}
```

Live example of code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lREClUJEatbvenMWroTZ?p=preview)

I except that service is created once and when each component call WriteToLog method, the output is the same in each component but it's not.

**Example of output :**

The App-Component can output this :

> Instance 1 - Created at Thu Jan 21 2016 11:43:51
>
> From App-Component - This is Thu Jan 21 2016 11:43:54
>
> From App-Component - This is Thu Jan 21 2016 11:43:55

and the Sub-Component can output this :

> Instance 2 - Created at Thu Jan 21 2016 11:43:51
>
> From Sub-Component - This is Thu Jan 21 2016 11:43:57
>
> From Sub-Component - This is Thu Jan 21 2016 11:43:58

So it appear that 2 instance of service is created (instance 1 + instance 2)

I only want one instance ;) and when I append string in log, this must appear in both component.

Thank you for your help

Comment: FYI, Angular 2 is not called AngularJS 2.

Answer (score 32):

**update Angular >= 2.0.0-RC.6**

Don't add the service to the providers of the component. 
Instead add it to

```ts
@NgModule({ providers: [...], ...
```

(of a module that is **not** lazy loaded because lazy loaded modules introduce their own scope)

```ts
@Component ({
    selector : 'Sub-Component',
    template : `<hr>
            This is the Sub-Component !
            <BR>
            StateService Log : 
            <pre>{{ _stateService.log }}</pre>
            <button (click)="WriteToLog ()">Write to log</button>
            `,
    // providers : [StateService] <== remove
})
```

**Angular <=2.0.0-RC.5**

If you add it on a component you get a new service instance for each component instance. Instead add it to

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [StateService]);
```

You can have more fine-grained control by adding it to a single component, then this component and all children get the same instance injected but otherwise the application works with the instance created by `bootstrap()`. This is the "hierarchical" in Angulars DI.

See also
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

Comment: +1 I''ve found it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModule-interface.html#!#bootstrap-anchor) - but it is not clear that this is the place that I should put the call to the service. also  - without testing - where does it say that each component being injected with a service - will create a new instance ?

Comment: Good question. I haven't seen it explicitly mentioned in the docs, but there are a lot of docs and I haven't read them all. I learned it from discussions during development of AngularDart 1.0. DI maintains a single instance per provider. Every provider instance leads to one service instance. This is why you get multiple instances if you provide a service on a component that is added multiple times to your application. For providers added globally (AppComponent, NgModule), there will ever be only a single instance.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've tried it with the latest angular version and I can't find the place to put it so it can run once ( see console) https://plnkr.co/edit/LvO6yVOQjKoCVogK7HRh?p=preview

Comment: If you provide it in the `AppModule` (and only there) it's the safest place to be a singleton. You can also provide it at an imported `@NgModule()`, but here you have to take special precautions if it is a lazy loaded module. https://plnkr.co/edit/JYZrPMvIdrtMtbltbMIz?p=preview

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added it as `bootstrap: [ AppComponent , ExampleService ]` ,and there's an error https://plnkr.co/edit/RnDdc29A4j1Kit4VZqdQ?p=preview

Comment: I made it more clear in my answer. Adding providers to `bootstrap()` is only for older Angular2 versions.

Comment: If you want a single instance for your whole application, put it in `@NgModule(...)`. If you want a single instance for each component instance (and it's children) and the service should not be available outside the component, then put it in the `@Component(...)`

Comment: Do we know why if I provide a service only once *(even with `forRoot()`)* in a parent module it will get instanciated 2 times: 1 when parent instances and another when child instances?

Comment: Probably not without seeing a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the Günter's great answer, this link could perhaps give more details about how the hierarchical dependency injection of Angular2 works:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397#34807397).