# How to avoid multiple instances of a service in Angular Dart

Tags: angular-dart

It seems that each component that creates its own instance of [a] service. I don't understand why.

I note this [AngularJs 2 - multiple instance of service created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929665/angularjs-2-multiple-instance-of-service-created), but I'm not clear on the correct solution. Do I create the service instance `_myService` in main:

```
 void main() {
  bootstrap(AppComponent,[MyService]);
 }
```

and then copy it to [child] components (because I also remove `MyService` from the component providers)? This doesn't seem correct, because the components reference `_myService` before it's instantiated, and I have to check it for being null.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use factory constructor pattern like [here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors).

Answer (score 0):

Creating your service in the bootstrap will make sure there is only one instance of it for the app (if you don't provide it again in some component).

You get multiple copies of it only if you provide it in some @Component - then each instance of the component (and all its children) will have a separate instance of the service.

Comment: "Creating your service in the bootstrap will make sure there is only one instance of it for the app." - but it doesn't. I get several intances. So, if I remove  MyService from component providers, how do the components access the instance from the bootstrap? Thanks,s

Comment: DI is closely related to the DOM tree in Angular - if you provide something on the app level any component can Inject it.