# Ng2 Data sharing between components via Services

Tags: angular, typescript

I am still facing the same problem, after following each steps.

[Angular2 data Sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273106/angular2-share-data-between-components-using-services/43167311#43167311)

Still Not able to share the data between components via Shared Services.

My Workflow: After login via Login's Service, I wanted to share the UserDetails Response to the About Page.

I have only injected the Login Service in app.module.ts in @NgModule as providers

===Login Component=====

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { UserAccount } from '../model/userAccount.interface';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})

export class LoginComponent  { 

emailAddress : string;
password : string;
submitted : boolean;
errorMessage : string;

constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router : Router) {
    this.submitted = false;
}

login() {
    // event.preventDefault();
    this.submitted = true;
    this.loginService.getLogin(this.emailAddress, this.password).subscribe(
        u => this.router.navigate(['/about']),
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

}

===Login Service====

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
   private userAccount : UserAccount[];

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

getLogin(): Observable<UserAccount[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.url)
                .map(this.extractData);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  this.userAccount = body.data.user[0]
  return this.userAccount || { };
}

 getUserDetails() {
  return this.userAccount;
}
}
```

======About Component=====

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit{

// initialize a private variable _data, it's a BehaviorSubject
// private _data = new BehaviorSubject<UserAccount[]>([]);
userDetails : UserAccount[];
lService : LoginService;

constructor(loginService: LoginService) {
    this.lService = loginService;
    this.userDetails = this.lService.getUserDetails();
    console.log(this.userDetails);
}

ngOnInit() {

}
}
```

Comment: Will you please post full code of component.

Comment: updated the Login Component. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @siddh what is `getUserDetails()`?

Comment: sorry my mistake, the getUserDetails() returns the return this.userAccount; I have updated the login.service.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.map(this.extractData);`

to

```
.map((res)=>this.extractData(res));
```

or `.map(this.extractData.bind(this));`

your `this` is not refering to your component inside the `map` function in the first one.

Comment: @siddh Glad I could help :-)