# Using shared service data share between two components in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-components

I am working on angular 2 application with open layer map. in that i need to share the location coordinate from one components to other components using share services.

searchcomponents.ts

```
 bounds: any;
placesChanged() {
    var places = this.searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places == null) return;
    if (places == undefined) return;
    if (places.length == 0) return;

    this.searchResultsSource.clear();

    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    places.forEach(this.processPlace.bind(this));

    // if the drawn result(s) is only one
    if (this.searchResultsSource.getFeatures().length == 1) {
        var singleFeature = this.searchResultsSource.getFeatures()[0];
        this.pos = singleFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        console.log(this.pos ,"hanumanh" );
        this.service.setUrlHistoryObj(this.pos);
    }
```

i want to share pos value to other components.
this is my service code

Search.services.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
public pos : string;
public invokeEvent:Subject<any> = new Subject<string>();
constructor() {   
this.pos="";
 }
public setUrlHistoryObj(val: string): void {
        this.pos = val;
        console.log(val);
    }
    public getUrlHistoryObj(): string {
        return this.pos;    
  }
```

in this i am getting the pos value as geocoordinate and i want to share that pos value to other components.

Buffer.components.ts

```
value1: string;

constructor(
    private urlHistoryService:SearchService) {

    this.value1 = this.urlHistoryService.getUrlHistoryObj();
   // this.value1 = this.urlHistoryService.setUrlHistoryObj();

}
```

i am getting error undefined. please help me.

Comment: Where are you providing this service?

Comment: @echonax i am providing this service in  searchcomponents.ts to get the pos value. and i want to share in Buffer.components.ts .
sorry i am new to angular . if i did any mistake please guide me.

Comment: Can you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997489/component-service-global-variable-change-content/43997672#43997672 and tell me if its the same issue?

Comment: @echonax i am not using `@NgModule`  and service is singleton i already put providers :[SearchService] in that.

Comment: Can you create a plunker, It's hard to tell from your description what is giving you the error and whether or not it's coming from bad syntax or a legitimate error in your data flow

Comment: @user2635445 where did you put `providers :[SearchService]`? Can you include it in your question?

Comment: this question looks like the exact same setup you're trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273106/angular2-share-data-between-components-using-services?rq=1

Comment: @user2635445 so how is your service a singleton? Please read the links carefully. You need to define the provider in a higher level than these two components.

Comment: please post the @ngModule code

Comment: Not sure if that is your real code, but you cannot get anything from `this` in `constructor`. I.e. for `BufferComponent` it should be `this.value1 = urlHistoryService.getUrlHistoryObj()`

Comment: @Likwid_T  `@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RoiCreateComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    BufferDialogComponent,
    
  ],
    providers: [
    RoiService,
    ArticleService,
    RoiDialogService,
    ArticleDialogService,
    FacebookService,
    AppService,
    LoginService,
    BufferDialogService
  ],
  entryComponents: [RoiDialogComponent, ArticleDialogComponent, BufferDialogComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})`

Comment: @A.Tim i tried but its not working.

Comment: @user2635445 have you applied the solution that I've given in the link above? Remove the service from both of your `@Component`s and add it to the `@NgModule`

Comment: @echonax i put service provider in ` @Component({
  selector: 'poi-buffer',
  template: `
   < html code>
 `,
  providers:[SearchService],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})              `

Comment: @user2635445 and I'm trying to tell you that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @echonax can u please tell me how to do it right.

Comment: @user2635445 aren't you reading my comments? :-)

Comment: @echonax i remove the services from `@components` and add to the `@NgModule` and its working. thank you very much

Comment: @user2635445 Glad I could help. We should mark it as a duplicate then :-)

Comment: @echonax thank you very much for guidance.