# Angular2 - Sharing Data Between Components Using Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-components

I am trying to share data between components using a common shared service.  This is the service.

```
@Injectable()
export class JobService {
    public jobType=null;
    public examples=[];
}
```

This is my first component.  The full code within the component is much too long so I've just added a `...` to represent the rest of the code but inside this component the `jobType` and `examples` variables of the service are set.

```
@Component({
            selector: 'app-job',
            templateUrl: './job.component.html'
})
export class JobComponent implements OnInit {

          constructor(private jobService: JobService, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
            }
    ...

}
```

and the second component is

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-preview',
    template:'./preview.component.html'
})
export class PreviewComponent implements OnInit {

    jobType;
    examples;

    constructor(private jobService: JobService) {
    }  
    ngOnInit() {

        this.jobType=this.jobService.jobType;
        this.examples=this.jobService.examples;
    }

}
```

So the idea is that it should be able to get the `jobType` and `examples` variables that were set within the service inside `JobComponent`.

The service itself is provided in the module file

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        JobComponent,
        JobListComponent,
        JobDetailsComponent,
        PreviewComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        TabsModule
    ],
    providers: [JobService]
})
export class JobModule {

}
```

It is my understanding that this means that `JobService` is instantiated only once and is shared between the components.

The problem arises within the html template of `JobComponent`.  It contains a router link to open the `PreviewComponent` in a new tab i.e.

```
<a target="_blank" routerLink="/preview">Preview</a>
```

When this link is opened, the variables within `JobService` have already been set in `JobComponent` (I checked that this is true). The `/preview` route is associated with `PreviewComponent`.  When the new window opens 
and `PreviewComponents` reads the `JobService` variables, they have not been set which leads me to believe that `PreviewComponent` has created an entirely new instance of `JobService`.  However, according to 
[Angular2 - Share data between components using services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273106/angular2-share-data-between-components-using-services)
This should not happen if `JobService` is only provided once in the modules file.  Can anyone tell me why the `JobService` does not seem to be shared across these two components?

Comment: services instantiate once per window. they aren't shared between windows.  You need to use local storage or session storage to transfer data, or make the new tab an actual child of the original so they can commnunicate and you can call functions on the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're opening the page in a new window. The state of `JobService` is not being preserved. A possible solution could be passing the `JobService`'s state to the preview component using url query parameters and rebuilding the service in the new page for example, navigating to `/preview?jobType=something&examples=are,comma,separated,list` or saving the state in the browser (local storage, cookies, whatever) and reading it on page initialization

Comment: Thanks.  The number of examples could be in the hundreds so I think that's probably too large to put in routing params but the local storage idea might work - it might even be simpler that way, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To save the state of a shared resource you should use `BehaviorSubject`s.

```
@Injectable()
export class JobService {
    public jobType$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject('');
    public examples$: Behavior Subject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    public jobTypes = null;
    public examples = [];

    setJobType(jobType) {
        this.jobTypes = jobType;
        this.jobType$.next(this.jobTypes);
    }
    //set the same way for examples
}
```

Then in each of your components.

```
@Component({
            selector: 'app-job',
            templateUrl: './job.component.html'
})
export class JobComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private jobService: JobService, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  //somewhere like ngOnInit subscribe to jobType$ and or examples$

  //on some event or trigger of the ui call the setJobType method with changes.
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-preview',
    template:'./preview.component.html'
})
export class PreviewComponent implements OnInit {

    jobType;
    examples;

    constructor(private jobService: JobService) {
    }  
    ngOnInit() {
        this.jobService.jobType$.subscribe(result => this.jobType = result);
        this.jobService.examples$.subscribe(result => this.examples = result);
    }
}
```