# Should lazy loaded service destroy outside routes in standalone?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-routing

I'm using Angular standalone (bootstrapApplication etc.).

I'm following the docs here [Providing services to a subset of routes](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#providing-services-to-a-subset-of-routes) to lazy load a service which works.

```
export const ROUTES: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    providers: [
      AdminService,
      {provide: ADMIN_API_KEY, useValue: '12345'},
    ],
    children: [
      {path: 'users', component: AdminUsersComponent},
      {path: 'teams', component: AdminTeamsComponent},
    ],
  },
  
  // ... other application routes that don't
  //     have access to ADMIN_API_KEY or AdminService.
];
```

My issue is that when I navigate outside the `admin/` route the service doesn't self destroy. I'm logging out `ngOnDestroy` and constructor calls to confirm this.

- I've left the service with no providedIn i.e. `@Injectable()`.
- It's not included it in the bootstrap providers array, only the route providers.
- inside the `admin/` routes each component has a provided store service component that injects the `AdminService` via `service = inject(AdminService)`. Each store service does get destroyed on navigation.

Should the service self destroy automatically?

This answer to another question suggests not https://stackoverflow.com/a/75835854/4711754 but I wanted to check before coming up with a way of force destroying the `AdminService`.