Angular NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken errror
I' m receiving the error  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken IPublicationsRequestService! in my app when injecting my service in any component or resolver (all part of the module where the actual service is defined).
The service should be injectable as a concrete class or as an interface using an injection token so in my lazy-loaded module I have defined :
in publications-request.module.ts:
providers:[
 {
  provide: PUBLICATIONS_REQUEST_SERVICE_TOKEN,
  useExisting: PublicationsRequestService
 },
 PublicationsRequestService
]

However, if instead of providing this service in the lazy-loaded module where it is defined, I provide it to the root app.module of the application:
in app.module.ts :
 providers:[
 {
  provide: PUBLICATIONS_REQUEST_SERVICE_TOKEN,
  useExisting: PublicationsRequestService
 },
 PublicationsRequestService
]

then all works fine !
Of course I dont want to define this provider at root level. So what am I missing here ? Should it not work the way I did it in my publications-request module where all components/services/resolvers are defined ?
FYI, the service is define as  :
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class PublicationsRequestService extends 
  BaseRepositoryService<PublicationsRequest> implements 
  IPublicationsRequestService { }


Can you provide a StackBlitz or a more complete code sample? The dependency system is a tree and it sounds like you're running into a situation where the component attempting to use the service is on a different branch of the tree (which is why adding the service to the providers array of the root module is causing the injection to succeed - the root is the trunk of the tree). If you're using the service outside the module it's provided from, you'll need to import the containing module wherever the service is needed (good approach) or promote the service to root (worse approach).

One thing that stands out is that you're including your service in the root of the application already by specifying providedIn: 'root' in the service definition (this shouldn't have an impact on the lazyness/eagerness of the module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53010605/14956277).

Here's a StackBlitz showing a service provided in a lazy module being used by components in the same module and by components in other modules via import: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xanmme3x Notice that all three uses have different instances (because the service is provided by the module which is being loaded once by itself, once by the first feature, and once by the second). A root-level provider would have resulted in the same instance for all three usages of the service.

Also, off-topic, but standalone components/pipes/directives have been available since Angular 14 and are currently preferred (so much so that the team made the standalone field on the respective decorators default to true now). There's a fairly painless migration if you want to get away from the NgModule approach and to an approach that might be a bit clearer about its dependency graphs: https://angular.dev/reference/migrations/standalone

@DM ,  my service must have a single instance. This is the reason I use Use existing and not UseClass. Thanks for the tip regarding standalone components but I already migrated some of them. I still need to be able to inject the service in module-scope components.

Gotcha, then you definitely need to provide the service at the root. Once it's there, you don't need to "reprovide" the existing instance unless you want to. The components in other modules are happy to continue looking up the tree past their own module to find a provider.

Let me know if you have questions and I can whip together another demo.
