# How to inject a provider in Angular 2 service from action?

Tags: angular, redux, angular2-services, injectableprovider

I am trying to remove the dependency of components on services in Angular with the help of Redux.

Basically, the flow is **Component -> Action -> Service**

In the service I want to use http module of @angular/core, which is suggested to be passed in the constructor:

```
export class SampleService {
    constructor(public http: Http) {}
}
```

And as I am calling service from action, it won't get the http provider as I do not have an instance of http provider in it.

```
export default class SampleAction {
    private _projectService;
    constructor() {
        this._sampleService = new SampleService();
    }
}
```

How can I inject the http provider into the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action you can inject the Http in constructor and pass it into the service instance. Something like

```
export default class SampleAction {
    private _projectService;
    constructor(@Inject(Http) http: Http) {
        this._sampleService = new SampleService(http);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to instantiate the service by your own. Just inject the service into a component or another service. What is important is to have the provider configured for this execution flow. In your case, Http (and more generally `HTTP_PROVIDERS`) and `SampleSampleService`. Providers are defined for the whole application (at the bootstrap level) or for component (`providers` attribute).

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS, SampleService ]);
```

or

```
@Component({
  providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS, SampleService ]
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private action: SampleAction) {
  }

  executeAction() {
    this.action.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Here is the code you should use for your `SampleAction` class:

```
export default class SampleAction {
  constructor(private _projectService: SampleService) {
  }
}
```

You can notice that to be able to inject into a service, the `@Injectable` need to be used.

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
  constructor(public http: Http) {}
}
```

This answer could give you more hints about the way to use dependency injection and how hierarchical injectors work in Angular2:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: Thanks for the help Thierry, but I am looking for a solution in which the component must not know about the service.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "must not know about the service"? How would your component call the service?

Comment: The component should dispatch an action like in flux/redux and the action then will use a middleware to call the service.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a service instance using `new SomeService()`.

Instead just add the classes to the providers of `bootstrap(.., [Providers])` or the component that should be the root of the scope where a service instance should be shared.

Also add all dependencies (constructor arguments) to the providers list.

If all is set up correctly, everywhere where an instance is requested by a constructor argument, an instance with all dependencies automatically resolved is passed in.

Just configure DI and let it do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gunter, but I am looking for a solution in which the component must not know about the service.