# Angular2: Need to add provider in component for dependency on service?

Tags: service, dependency-injection, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular

I'm having some trouble understanding the logic that Angular2 uses when it comes to dependency injection. This is my situation:

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Demo1Service} from './demo-1.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<div>test template</div>`,
    providers: [Demo1Service]
})
class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _demo1Service: Demo1Service) {}
}

export {AppComponent};
```

**demo-1.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Data1Store} from './data-1.store';

@Injectable()
class Demo1Service {
    constructor(private _data1Store: Data1Store) {}
};

export {Demo1Service};
```

**data-1.store.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
class Data1Store {}

export {Data1Store};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4aBNbAxtHbUvVqxPRUbv?p=preview

If you run this plunker you will see that Angular needs a provider for the Data1Store to be defined in the AppComponent. In order to have some separation of concerns, I would prefer that the AppComponent doesn't need to know about the existence of the Data1Store.

Is there something I'm here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the provider needs to present when executing the `Demo1Service` service. Because of hierarchical injectors, it's not mandatory to have the corresponding provider defined at the component level.

This can also be done for the whole application or within a parent injector. Defining this provider when bootstrapping your application seems to be what you need:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ Demo1Service, Data1Store ]);
```

This way you don't need to define your service providers within the `providers` attribute of your component

Here is an overview of all these elements and there relations:

```
Application
     |
AppComponent  --- Demo1Service --- Data1Store
```

In such application, we have two injectors:

- The application injector that can be configured using the second parameter of the `bootstrap` function
- The `AppComponent` injector that can be configured using the `providers` attribute of this component. It can "see" elements defined in the application injector. This means if a provider isn't found in this provider, it will be automatically look for into this parent injector. If not found in the latter, a "provider not found" error will be thrown.
  This question could give you more details about how hierarchical injectors of Angular work:
- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: Thanks for that! Since I will be working with multiple data stores, I will create a class that exports an array of all the data store classes. Adding that array to the bootstrap dependencies should work out fine.