# Application wide service with NOT application wide dependency service in bootstrap

Tags: angular

That question is continues my last question
[No provider for ObservableDataService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484714/no-provider-for-observabledataservice)

So, i have application wide service `UploadedTemplatesService` which must be singleton. That service have one dependency - `ObservableDataService` and that dependency must create for that singletone `UploadedTemplatesService` only once, but `ObservableDataService` can be used in other services too and that service must inject for each other services as new object each time.

Must important note - i want to use `UploadedTemplatesService` inside Route hook too, so i added to bootstrap `.then` method and inside `.then` add appRef.injector inside `AppInjector` function.
`AppInjector` code:

```

```
export const AppInjector = (injector?: Injector): Injector => {
    if (injector) {
        appInjectorRef = injector;
    }
    return appInjectorRef;
};
```

```

So after that, i can get `UploadedTemplatesService` inside Route hook in way like `Injector.get(UploadedTemplateService)`.

So, i looked at documentation and tryed to write something like

```

```
bootatrap(AppComponent, [
    provide(UploadedTemplatesService, {
        useFactory: () => {
            return new UploadedTemplatesService(new ObservableDataService());
        }
    })
])
```

```

But that code throw new error: `Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined`

What i done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
provide(ServiceA, {
    useValue: new ServiceA(new CollectionService<ServiceADataType>())
})
```

That works. So, why useFactory throws `Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined` error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you try to do but if you want to use `useFactory` and also have `ObservableDataService` available in dependency injection, you should use something like that:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ObservableDataService,
  provide(UploadedTemplatesService, {
    useFactory: (dataService: ObservableDataService) => {
      return new UploadedTemplatesService(dataService)
    },
    deps: [ObservableDataService]
 })
);
```

That said, by specifying `UploadedTemplatesService` and `ObservableDataService` providers at the `bootstrap` level you will have singletons for these services...

Comment: No, ObservableDataService must be not application wide. Only UploadedTemplateService, which has one dependency - ObservableDataService

Comment: Because each object of ObservableDataService can contain his own data.

For example i want to create another application wide service BlablablaService, and that service will store his data inside his dependency ObservableDataService.

ObservableDataService - just a collection based on rxjs

Comment: Okay, I think I understood what you try to do. But in this case, ObservableDataService can't take part into constructor-based dependencyclopédie injection... It seems to be what you want. Do you still try to inject this service somewhere in your application?

Comment: I still try to do that. About `Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined` error - i have no idea why that happens, because i do that like in Angular 2 documentation (example with V8 engine), but instead empty constructor i set ObservableDataService in constructor

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to import the `ObservableDataService` type ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103979/discussion-between---and-thierry-templier).

Comment: No. But if i can't use ObservableDataService in DI - this so stupid limitation. In every app can be many application-wide (singletons) services, thats require other services as dependencies.

Comment: So you need to have a provider configured for it... And Angular2  will manage instances by itself.

Comment: provider, which will passed into bootstrap?

I tried do that

`provide(UploadedTemplatesService, {
        useFactory: () => {
            return new UploadedTemplatesService(new ObservableDataService());
        }
    })
`
but it throw error. And i does not find any other ways to do that.