# Angular2 - inject into @Injectable

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, injectable

I have an `Angular2` app with a `service` that is used for getting a data from an API. Following [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#non-class-dependencies) example, I want to create a separate file which should contain some configuration data. My problem is that my service has an `@Injectable()` decorator and I'm not sure if I can pass it a `provide` array in the metadata in which I will inject the configuration as shown in the tutorial. Anybody ever faced such a problem is welcome to share his solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, Angular2 leverages hierarchical injectors and injectors are linked to components. In short you can define providers only on components (`providers` property) or at application level (`bootstrap` function).

Regarding services, they will be able to use providers that are visible for the component that initiated the call but you can't define providers at their levels.

Here is a sample:

```
Application
     |
AppComponent
     |
ChildComponent
  getData()     --- Service1 --- Service2
```

In such application, we have three injectors:

- The application injector that can be configured using the second parameter of the `bootstrap` function
- The `AppComponent` injector that can be configured using the `providers` attribute of this component. It can "see" elements defined in the application injector. This means if a provider isn't found in this provider, it will be automatically look for into this parent injector. If not found in the latter, a "provider not found" error will be thrown.
- The `ChildComponent` injector that will follow the same rules than the `AppComponent` one. To inject elements involved in the injection  chain executed forr the component, providers will be looked for first in this injector, then in the `AppComponent` one and finally in the application one.

This means that when trying to inject the `Service1` into the `ChildComponent` constructor, Angular2 will look into the `ChildComponent` injector, then into the `AppComponent` one and finally into the application one.

Since `Service2` needs to be injected into `Service1`, the same resolution processing will be done: `ChildComponent` injector, `AppComponent` one and application one.

This means that both `Service1` and `Service2` can be specified at each level according to your needs using the `providers` attribute for components and the second parameter of the `bootstrap` function for the application injector.

This answer could help you:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: Of course, another good reference regarding the DI capabilities in Angular 2 can be found here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit strange, but only components can configure dependency injection in Angular (well, and `bootstrap()`, but that is essentially the same as the root component).  I.e., only components can specify providers.

As @Thierry mentions in his answer, each component in the component tree will get an associated "injector" if the component has a `providers` array specified.  We can think of this like an injector tree, that is (normally much) sparser than the component tree.  When a dependency needs to be resolved, this injector tree is consulted.  The first injector that can satisfy the dependency does so.  The injector tree is walked up, toward the root component/injector.

So, in order for your service to inject a configuration object dependency, that config object first has to be registered with an injector.  I.e., in a component's `providers` array, call
 `provide(stringToken or OpaqueToken, {useValue: MyConfigObject} )`  
This registration must occur somewhere at or above the component where you want to use/inject your service.

Your service should then be able to `@Inject` the registered config object, because it will find it in the injector tree.

Note, since only components can configure providers, the `@Injectable()` decorator does not support any configuration options, so a `providers` array is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I can mark only one as "The answer" but your one is worthy, too :)

Comment: @RadoslavStoyanov, no problem. DI can be a bit confusing at first (until you learn about the injector tree), so sometimes a slightly different wording or explanation can help people.  I wanted to highlight the injector tree part.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. For services the providers need to be added to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [..., Service, ServiceDependency1, ...])`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622