# Nested Services in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

When nesting a service into another service in Angular 2 no typescript errors are thrown. However, when the page with the top component is loaded, the following error is logged in the console: `EXCEPTION: No provider for ConfigService! (AdminAreaComponent -> CoreService -> ConfigService)`

What do I need to do to prevent this?

**app.ts:**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AdminAreaComponent} from './components/adminArea.component'
var adminArea = bootstrap(AdminAreaComponent);
```

**adminArea.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {CoreService} from '../services/core.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'admin-area',
    templateUrl: 'partials/adminArea.html',
    providers: [CoreService]
})
export class AdminAreaComponent {
    constructor(private coreService: CoreService) {}
}
```

**core.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
import {ConfigService} from './config.service'

@Injectable()
export class CoreService {
    constructor(private configService : ConfigService) { }
}
```

**config.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: `providers: [CoreService, ConfigService]`

Comment: If you're interested in knowing why Eric's and Günter's answers work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582613/angular2-inject-into-injectable/35582685#35582685

Comment: So in order to get rid of all errors I should import the relevant services and define their providers in multiple files?

Comment: I had a similar problem yesterday. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582613/angular2-inject-into-injectable) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems `ConfigService` is not listed with the providers in

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [... CoreService, ConfigService])
```

or in the providers list of the component (if you want to limit the scope of the service) as mentioned by Eric.

Comment: Shouldn't each service be able to define its own components? If they must be listed globally, wouldn't that make Angular 2 not very modular?

Comment: I also think this should be improved. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/35756813/217408