# How to use providers in a service?

Tags: angular

I need use multiple instances of one service.

Usually when I use one instance of this service in component, I write like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'one-component',
    providers: [provide("token1", {useClass: Service})],
    template: `
        <h1>App</h1>
    `
})
export class OneComponent {
    constructor(@Inject('token1') service:Service) {}
}
```

But now I need use this service in Service2, I write like this:

```
export class Service2 {
    constructor(@Inject('token1') service:Service) {}
}
```

As you know, it shows:

> No provider

Because `Service2` does not have `providers: [provide("token1", {useClass: Service})]`. But where can I add it since it does not have `@Component`?

Thanks

Comment: where do you use your Service2 then ?

Comment: @Ludohen thanks for help, I use Service2 in a component.

Comment: Then what you're trying to do is definitely possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly configuring services this way is currently not supported and currently there are no plans to add support https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Gunter's answer is fully correct here.
If I understood Hongbo Miao's issue correctly, this can be "easily" achieve.
If you want to get a new instance of a service on every injection you'd have to use `useFactory` instead of `useClass` provider configuration.

Then if you get a no provider error for `"token1"` in `Service2` it's because it's not configure on the right injector, sibling or parent of `OneComponent` ... where `Service2` is injected.

**Edit:**

For this to work you would have to define your `Service` and `Service2` provider at the root component (for instance). In this case, all will share the same instance of the services.

If you want to have different instances in each components, then define the providers at the component level, where the services are being used.

```ts
@Component({
  providers: [Service, Service2],
  // Other config props
})
export class RootComponent {
}

@Component({
  // Config props
})
export class OneComponent {
  constructor(public service: Service) {}
  methodx() {
    this.service...
  }
}

@Component({
  // Config props
})
export class TwoComponent {
  constructor(public service: Service2) {}
  methodx() {
    this.service...
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
  constructor(public service: Service) {
  }
}
```

Using the `@Inject('StringToken')` is not the best thing you do and is not the recommended way. Use Type token instead (as done in the code above).

Resources:

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Based on your code and what I want, I have another `ThreeComponent` which also uses `Service`, and I want `OneComponent` and `ThreeComponent` use different instances of `Service`. That is why I add token when uses `Service`. Then in `Service2` I have no way to use `providers` for `Service`.

Comment: `Service2` doesn't need anything special, providers are defined above in the injector tree

Comment: I have got a similar issue. Service2 needs Service1. 

> Component1 and Component2 need different instances of Service1. So I cannot provide Service1 in the root. 

> If I provide Service1 at component level means provider in both Component1 and Component2, I cannot use it in Service2.

> If I provide in both root and component level, I get multiple service instantiation issue.
I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected this error (Using a service B into a service A) by declaring the two services in `app.module.ts`'s providers array.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports:      [...],
    providers:    [
        ServiceA,
        ServiceB,
    ],
    bootstrap:    [...],
})
```