# How do I get the id of a form input element for a label in a reusable Angular component template?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 component that holds some form input elements and labels that should be associated with them. Multiple instances of the component might be in the page at once. How do I set the `for` attribute of the `label` and the `id` attribute of the `input` to connect them to each other?

If I hard-code the id of the input element in the template then it won't be unique on the page. But I don't want to have to pass an identifier into this component from its containing component; the connection between the label and form element is just this component's concern.

```
<div>
    <label for="???">Name</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="name" type="text" id="???"/>
</div>
```

AngularJS had a scope $id property that could be used to build a unique id. Does Angular have anything similar for components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the @Input decorator and pass values from parent where you have the component to the child component where your form or lable is

parentcomponent

```
<myComponent idToUse="id1"></myComponent>
<myComponent idToUse="id2"></myComponent>
```

ChildComponent

```
@Component({
selector : "myComponent",
template: `<div>
    <label for="{{idToUse}}">Name</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="name" type="text" id="{{idToUse}}"/>
</div>`
})
export class childComponent {
@Input() idToUse;
}
```

You can find a similar example  for using same compnent multiple times in this link [Angular2 .. Using the same component to show different data on the same page depending on service response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372515/angular2-using-the-same-component-to-show-different-data-on-the-same-page-dep/44374725#44374725)