# Use RouteParams in a service in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a service like the following:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

@Injectable()
export class QService {
  /* A service to handle a query (q) in the search string.
   */
  constructor(
      private _router:Router,
      routeParams:RouteParams
    ) {
    /* Set this._q from the search string.
     */
    this._q = routeParams.get('q');
  }

  private _q:string
  get q():string {
    return this._q;
  }
  set q(q:string) {
    this._q = q;
    // TODO Add q back to the search string.
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, no matter how I use this service, I get an error along the lines of `No provider for RouteParams`.  I'm stumped.  Is there some recommended or simple way of doing this I've missed?

Comment: Did you add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS])`?

Comment: This comment is longer than necessary because of Stack Overflow's somewhat strange rules.  Yes I do.

Comment: Can you try: QService.params = [[Router],[RouteParams]] at the very end of your code? Also, I add injectables: [RouteParams], but this inside my @Component. May be you can try this as well

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to specify this service at the level of a component (involved in routing) within its providers attribute and not when bootstrapping your application:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ QService]
})
export class...
```

As a matter of fact RouteParams only applies in the context of a component and not globally to the application. So the application injector doesn't have knowledge of this provider since it's present in a child injector only (a component one).

This is linked to dependency injection and hierarchical injectors. See this question for more details:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: I do use the service as a provider as indicated.  If I remove anything to do with routing, the service works as expected.  However, it seems like terrible isolation of concern to have a component wrap the service and handle changes to the search string.  Especially since I also want the search string to update when q changes.  I'd be happy to see the "correct" way that angular has prescribed to do this.