# Angular 2 - Using Shared Service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Looks like shared services is the best practice to solve many situations such as communication among components or as replacement of the old $rootscope concept of angular 1. I'm trying to create mine, but it's not working. Any help ? ty !!!

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {OtherComponent} from './other.component';
import {SharedService} from './services/shared.service';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
providers: [SharedService],
directives: [OtherComponent],
template: `
    <button (click)="setSharedValue()">Add value to Shared Service</button>
    <br><br>
    <other></other>
`
})
export class AppComponent { 
data: string = 'Testing data';
setSharedValue(){
    this._sharedService.insertData(this.data);
    this.data = '';
    console.log('Data sent');
}
constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){}
}
```

other.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {SharedService} from './services/shared.service';
@Component({
selector : "other",
providers : [SharedService],
template : `
I'm the other component. The shared data is: {{data}}
`,
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit{
data: string[] = [];
constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){}
ngOnInit():any {
    this.data = this._sharedService.dataArray;
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of time, you need to define your shared service when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

and not defining it again within the `providers` attribute of your components. This way you will have a single instance of the service for the whole application.

---

In your case, since `OtherComponent` is a sub component of your `AppComponent` one, simply remove the `providers` attribute like this:

```
@Component({
  selector : "other",
  // providers : [SharedService], <----
  template : `
    I'm the other component. The shared data is: {{data}}
  `,
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit{
  (...)
}
```

This way they will shared the same instance of the service for both components. `OtherComponent` will use the one from the parent component (`AppComponent`).

This is because of the "hierarchical injectors" feature of Angular2. For more details, see this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: You're too fast :P  Here's a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/HX3LT9RaJD6ki3vpa1aW. Since the data is stored into an array, you need to also iterate over the array to display the separate pieces of info you store

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the bootstrap has changed in Angular 2 final. Do you guys have any idea how can I adapt the solution you provided? thanks!

Comment: Indeed, this provided solution does not seems to work on latest version of Angular 5. Bootstrap syntax has been also changed if you try that it will say `Service cannot be used as an entry component`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a global provider in your module, then you dont need to add this provider in each component. try this

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, InComponent],
    providers: [LoginService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(public loginService: LoginService) {

    }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(public loginService: LoginService) {

    }
}
```

I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your requirement and its solution, you can consider using Facade + Shared Services. I have a small project here: https://github.com/cmandamiento/angular-architecture-base

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you add a small example how to use Facade.