# Not able to get the data from shared service to component in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sharedservices

In our Angular 2 project. I am trying to use [shared services](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36251368/8101996) for communication between two components.

We've a `BotData.SharedService.ts` file like this:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
    import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    export interface Data {

        name: string,

    }

    @Injectable()
    export class BotDataService {
        sharingData: Observable<Data[]>

      private _sharingData: BehaviorSubject<Data[]>;

      private dataStore: {
        sharingData: Data[]
      };


      constructor() {
        this.dataStore = { sharingData: [] };
        this._sharingData = <BehaviorSubject<Data[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
      }

      saveData(userData) {
          console.log(userData)
         this._sharingData.next(userData); 
      }

      getData()  {
        console.log('get data function called' +  JSON.stringify( this.sharingData ) );
        return this._sharingData.asObservable();
      }
    }
```

Here, we're passing data using `this._sharingData.next(userData);` inside `saveData(userData)`.
Hence, this same data shall be available inside `getData()`.
However, when we do `console.log('get data function called' +  JSON.stringify( this.sharingData )` this gives `undefined`.

Hence, `botdataservice.getData()` is breaking inside component:

```
   constructor(private botdataservice: BotDataService) {
        this.botdataservice = botdataservice;
        this.botdataservice.getData().subscribe(_sharingData => {
            //   this.userKonte = _sharingData;
              console.log(JSON.stringify(_sharingData));
          });
    }
```

What is the fix here?

Comment: where is the definition of next function method ??

Comment: The subject next method is used to send messages to an observable which are then sent to all subscribers of that observable. predefined function

Comment: Can you share the definition of 'next' function ?

Comment: i have referred this http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: You are calling get function in subscription whereas calling next function in save method. I don't think this would work.As per blog next method of observable is applicable to all subscriptions of observer which is not so in your example