# How to pass data from sub-view to main-view in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have two buttons on the main view: Login and Logout. Initially only Login button is shown:

...

```
<button type="button" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>
<button type="button" routerLink="/showlist" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-info" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Login button will display a sub-view, once user is authenticated there, I want to pass the result back to main view, if user is authenticated, I want to hide the 'Login' button and show the 'Logout' button.

How can I pass the data from a sub-view back to main view via 'router-outlet'?

Comment: Use a common service. Read this, I'm sure you'll find something fitting your case (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a service to share information between components. Once the user is authenticated you would want to set a property in this service that indicates the user is authenticated.

Once you have done that you can reference this service to determine if you should show hide something using *ngIf.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251368/angular-2-using-shared-service) is a question answered that is similar to yours.

Comment: yes, I've created a shared data service to be referenced by the two components (main-view and sub-view), and it works nicely. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To show and hide the button you will use the *ngif structural directive like:

```
<button *ngIf="!loggedIn" type="button" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>
<button *ngIf="loggedIn" type="button" routerLink="/showlist" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-info" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

The loggedIn should be a boolean in your component associated with the main-view.
I suppose that with the term main-view and sub-view you mean that you have a parent-component and a child-component (for the authentication) form respectively. If this is the case refer to [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) and select the communication that fits you best.