# Bind data to parent

Tags: angular

I have angular 5 project with the following structure:

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-list-view></app-list-view>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

In my `<app-header>` component I have a `<app-search></app-search>` component:

```
<div id="headerContent">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="../../../assets/images/logo.png"/>
    </div>

    <app-search></app-search>
</div>
```

In this search.component.html I have:

```
<div id="searchContent">
  <input [(ngModel)]="queryString" type="text" placeholder="Bijv. PHP developer, AngularJs"/>
  <button>Zoeken</button>
</div>
```

I would like to pass the data from the input field from the `app-search` component to the `app-list-view` component.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve communication between components that are not nested (aka parent-child) it to use a service. A useful example is the on in [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

Comment: Yea just found this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/60ncOxHwiOy8biiUc9mt?p=preview worked pretty good :)

Comment: Yeap, it is the same. Also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36251635/1729287).

Comment: Oh yea that's better!