# Angular 2 DI query

Tags: angular

Refer to code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/j5qPROsWX2mGCQMIigee?p=info

It goes something like:

```
import {Component, Inject, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {Hamburger} from '../services/hamburger';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `Bun Type1: {{ bunType1 }}
  <br/>
  Are these same instances : {{equality}} 
  `
})
export class App {
  bunType: string;
  constructor(@Inject(Hamburger) h1, @Inject(Hamburger) h2) {
    this.bunType1 = h1.bun.type;


    if (h1 === h2) {
      this.equality = 'true'; //this is the outcome
    } else {
      this.equality = 'false';
    }

  }
}
```

In the app class, we are injecting two different variables h1 and h2.
I call them different because I believe the angular2 framework does something like

```
h1 = new Hamburger()
h2 = new Hamburger()
```

and now injects two different objects into App constructor. If that is the case then howcome we get the result (h1 === h2) = true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you specified the provider for the `Hamburger` class when bootstrapping your application, the corresponding instance is a singleton (instantiate once and then this instance is always used) for the whole application.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ Hamburger, (...) ]);
```

For that reason, when injecting a parameter with this provider (the `Hamburger` class), you will always have the same instance (even if you inject twice).

It doesn't depend on the names of parameters (h1 and h2) but on the tokens (in @Inject or the class names) you use.

It's the way dependency injection (and hierarchical injectors) works in Angular2. For more details, you could have a look at this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

This behavior allows for example to implement shared services, i.e. share à same service instance between several components with dependency injection.