# Angular2 Inject service in another service creates 2 instances

Tags: angular

I have two services: AuthService and MonBanquetService, and AuthService depends on MyService. Here's the basic code of these 2 services:

AuthService.ts:

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {MonBanquetService} from '../monbanquet.service'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    public username: string;

    constructor(protected _monBanquetService: MonBanquetService) {
        // do something()
    }

}
```

MonBanquetService.ts

```
import {Injectable, Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Injectable()
export class MonBanquetService {

    constructor(public http: Http, private _router: Router) {
        console.log('MonBanquetServices created');
    }
}
```

and I put these two services as providers in boot.ts:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    MonBanquetService,
    AuthService
]);
```

However, when I run the app, I see two console logs 'MonBanquetServices created'.
I thought services should be singletons, how is that there are two instances?

Thanks.

Comment: then Ideally you should only add `AuthService ` inside bootstrap dependency, which will create instance of `MonBanquetService` by acquiring it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular maintains a single instance per provider. If you add a type as provider at multiple places, this results in multiple instances.

When a key (type, token) is requested from DI it looks up the hierarchy and returns the instance from the first provider it finds.

Therefore if you want a global instance, only add it to the providers list of

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [MonBanquetService])
```

```
@NgModule(
  providers: [MonBanquetService],
  ....
)
export class AppMpdule{}
```

<strike>or as suggested by the Angular team for custom providers to the providers list of the root component</strike>

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [MonBanquetService]
})
class AppComponent {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it should not. You have to make sure that you don't use `providers` metadata into `@Component` decorator.

Look at here

- http://plnkr.co/edit/9Kg0DR36nuoTxRUNlIGY?p=preview

tried to implement what you showed and working as expected;

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you added the service into the "providers" attribute of your component. In this case, an instance of the service will be created for each component instance. And what you specified when bootstrapping your application won't be taken into account for this service...

It would be because of hierarchical injectors. Fore more details, you could have a look at this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)