# How can I call a service provider within another one - angularjs2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have some product and cart list. Here is the function to loop the cart list to get the particular product using id

```
getCartList(){
        this.cart = CART;
        this.cart.forEach((cart: Cart) => {
            let id = parseInt(cart.productid.trim());
              //**this.product = this._productService.getProduct(id); => Here I need to call another service.**
            });
        });
        console.log(this.cart);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define this service when bootstrapping your application and inject it in the service you want to use it:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ CardService , ProductService ]);
```

In the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CardService {
  constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {
  }
}
```

Don't forget to specify the @Injectable decorator.

This question could give more details on how dependency injection, hierarchical injectors and injection into services work:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)