# How to inject provider into component?

Tags: angular

How to inject provider into container component in Angular2?

For example I have parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myForm',
    template: '<form><myForm-detail></myForm-detail></form>',
    directives: [ MyFormDetailComponent ]
})
export class MyFormComponent {
    ...
}
```

And container component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myForm-detail',
    template: '<input type="text">',
    providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyFormDetailComponent {
    constructor(s: MyService) {
        console.log(s); // return "undefined"
    }

    ...
}
```

How to inject MyService into MyFormDetailComponent?

Comment: Euh, don't you inject it yet? ;-)

Comment: Or you mean into MyFormComponent and not MyFormDetailComponent?

Comment: What is the current behavior? Any error message? How does `MyService` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inject the same service into both component, you can simply define `MyService` into the `providers` attribute of the parent component. This way (and because of hierarchical injectors), you will be able to inject it into the two components:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myForm',
    template: '<form><myForm-detail></myForm-detail></form>',
    directives: [ MyFormDetailComponent ],
    providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyFormComponent {
  constructor(s: MyService) {
  }
  ...
}

(...)

@Component({
    selector: 'myForm-detail',
    template: '<input type="text">',
})
export class MyFormDetailComponent {
  constructor(s: MyService) {
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rUBgioLtqIAfWNCkRnlN?p=preview.

If you want to know more about hierarchical injectors, you could have a look at this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)