# No provider for service error in angular2, why do I need to inject it in it's parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I have a pages.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { ApiService } from '../../apiService/api.service';

import { Playlists } from '../shared/playlists.model';


@Injectable()
export class PagesService {

  private currentPlaylists: Subject<Playlists> = new BehaviorSubject<Playlists>(new Playlists());

  constructor(private service: ApiService) {

  }


}
```

This pages service needs another service called **ApiService**, I inject the way as shown above, it works.

I bootstrap ApiService in main.ts

```
import { ApiService }  from './apiService/api.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent,[
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  ApiService
]).catch((err: any) => console.error(err));;
```

But When I try to inject the ***PagesService*** to another component, it gives me error, No Provider for **PagesService**.
[image]

I write that component like this.

```
    import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

    import { MODAL_DIRECTVES, BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';


    import { ApiService } from '../../apiService/api.service';
    import { PagesService } from '../../pages/shared/pages.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'assign-playlist-modal',
      exportAs: 'assignModal',
      providers: [ PagesService ],
      directives: [MODAL_DIRECTVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
      viewProviders: [BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS],
      styleUrls: ['app/channel/shared/assignPlaylist.css'],
      templateUrl: 'app/channel/modals/assignPlaylistModal.html'
    })

    export class AssignPlaylistModalComponent {


      constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private pageService: PagesService, fb: FormBuilder) {
       }
}
```

**Update: this is my file structure**

```
channel/
--channel.component.ts
--shared/
----assignPlaylist.modal.ts
----addPlaylist.modal.ts
pages/
--shared/
----pages.service.ts
--pages.component.ts
```

Channel component is the parent of addPlaylist, addPlaylist is the parent of assignPlaylist.  This structure will not work

```
ChannelComponent       
       |
AddPlaylistComponent
       |
AssignPlaylistComponent     ----PagesService----ApiService
```

**I found one solution but don't know why I need to do that,**

I add the provider 'PagesService' to ChannelComponent, and also the AssignPlaylistComponent, it will work, no errors.

Even this will work

```
ChannelComponent            ----PagesService-------------
       |
AddPlaylistComponent
       |
AssignPlaylistComponent     ----ApiService---------------
```

However, I just want to use PagesService in AssignPlaylistComponent, so I think it not make sense to import PagesService in channelcomponent.ts and make a providers array in it.

Comment: i dont see ApiService in your providers list.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan I just edit my question, thanks

Comment: Not getting any error [Check this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eaJZVpahgHJpRu2MkR9A?p=preview). Is this the same scenario?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan  Update

Comment: Can you update the plunker with your scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit strange, but only components can configure dependency injection in Angular (well, and `bootstrap()`). I.e., only components can specify providers.

Each component in the component tree will get an associated "injector" if the component has a `providers` array specified. We can think of this like an injector tree, that is (normally much) sparser than the component tree. When a dependency needs to be resolved (by a component OR a service), this injector tree is consulted. The first injector that can satisfy the dependency does so. The injector tree is walked up, toward the root component/injector.

So, in order for your PagesService to inject a ApiService dependency, that ApiService object first has to be registered with an injector. I.e., in a component's `providers` array. This registration must occur somewhere at or above the component where you want to use/inject the ApiService .

Your service should then be able to inject the registered ApiService object, because it will find it in the injector tree.

See also [Angular 2 - Including a provider in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457913/angular-2-including-a-provider-in-a-service).