# Angular2 - Use Dependency Injection outside Components

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

In my app I use DI to pass information about the UserLogged around the different Components that need such info.
This means that I have a `main.ts` class like this

```ts
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {UserLogged} from './userLogged'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [UserLogged]);
```

and the components that need to use the instance of `UserLogged` have a constructor like this

```ts
constructor(private _user: UserLogged)
```

Now I would like to use the same instance of `UserLogged` also in simple TypeScript classes (which are not `@Component`). Is this possible? In other words, can I get hold of the same instance of `UserLogged` injected by DI also if I am outside a `@Component`?

Answer (score 3):

This constructor also works for services (other classes created by DI)

```ts
 bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherClass, UserLoggged]);

 @Injectable()
 export class UserLogged {
   log(text) {
     console.log(text);
   }
 }

 @Injectable()
 export class OtherClass {
   constructor(private _user: UserLogged) {}
 }

 class SomeComponent {
   constructor(private otherClass:OtherClass) {
     this.otherClass._user.log('xxx');
   }
 }
```

If you create these classes using `new SomeClass()` then you can inject it like

```ts
 class SomeComponent {
   constructor(private _injector:Injector) {
     let userLog = this._injector.get(UserLogged);
     new SomeClass(userLog);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the file where you bootstrap angular:

```js
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserLogged } from './userLogged';

declare global {
    var injector: Injector;
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [UserLogged]).then((appRef) => {
    injector = appRef.injector;
});
```

In your other file:

```js
import { UserLogged } from '../path/to/userLogged';

class TestClass {
    private userLogged: UserLogged;

    constructor() {
        this.userLogged = injector.get(UserLogged);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use dependency injection in classes you need to have a decorator, the `@Injectable` one.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeClass {
  constructor(private dep:SomeDependency) {
  }
}
```

The name `Injectable` isn't really self-explanatory. It's to make possible the injection within the class (and not into another class).

The provider for the `SomeDependency` class need to be visible from the component that initiates the call.

See this question for more details about dependency injection and hierarchical injectors:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Answer (score 0):

Im taking a wild guess here, but do you mean to say you want to Inject the class with having to use `providers : [UserLogged]` ? 
If that is the case, this will work

```
providers: [ provide(UserLogged, {useClass: UserLogged} ]
```

add the above to your bootstrap and you are good to go when you 'do not want to use @Component'

sample.ts

```
export class Sample{
   constructor(private ulog : UserLogged){}
}
```

In your case the bootstrap would be :

```
import {provide}   from   'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS}   from  'angular2/http';
bootstrap(AppComponent,[HTTP_PROVIDERS,provide(UserLogged, { useClass : UserLogged})]);
```

Ive added the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to demonstrate how to add multiple providers.
Cheers!