# Angular 2 - Parent and children communicate via a service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

This is connected to an cookbook example : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

I made a service with an observable, so components that are not directly connected can communicate.

Everything works nicely when there is an actual **grandchild** who is hooked to the **observable** and a **parent** who is listening.

My problem appears when I try to create the **grandchild** without a **parent** who is listening (`"No provider for service"`).

Like in the cookbook, the service should be a provider only inside a component that is listening  `providers: [MissionService]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't leverage the provider through the hierarchical injectors.

The easiest way to make this work is to define the provider for the service when bootstrapping the application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ MissionService ]);
```

Don't forget remove the service from the providers attribute of components.

This works when components have links together because a component looks for providers in its associated injector. If there is no match, it looks into its parent injector and so on:

```
Application
     |
AppComponent
     |
ChildComponent
    |
SubChildComponent
```

With no relation and defining provider in a component, the other component won't be able to find it.

For mode details about hierarchical injectors, you could have a look at this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: Thank you for the smooth explanation! By the way, it seems like I'm slacking behind you guys on Angular 2 knowledge, how do you guys know so much? Where do you look for answers (stackoverflow excluded)?

Comment: We now have Angular 2 live and Angular 4 at the door step.. Is this still valid?