# Angular 2, share an object between two components that have no direct relationship

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an app that is structured like this.

```
<app>
   <header>
      <component-a></component-a>
   </header>
   <div>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     <component-b></component-b>  <!-- loaded through router -->
   </div>
</app>
```

In `component-b` some data is retrieved and later set to a new object. For example, something like this..

```
 {
    infoThatComponentANeeds    : true,
    someMoreInfoAddedFromCompB : []
 }
```

This info is needed for the template in `component-a`. At first I tried to pass the info up to `component-a` via [@Outuput and eventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Output-var.html) using a custom event. But I was unable to get it to bubble up. I suspect that has to do with it being loaded through the router. So now I am trying to share the data between the two components using a shared service.

**My Service So Far:**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService
{
    public spec:Spec= null;

    public getSpec()
    {
        return this.spec;
    }
    public setSpec(spec:Spec)
    {
        this.spec = spec;
    }
}
```

**This is how I am trying to use it in component-a:**

```
ngDoCheck()
{
    if(this._sharedService.spec)
    {
        this.spec= this._sharedService.getSpec();
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**

After the spec is set in `component-b` and `ngDoCheck` from `component-a` checks to see if the spec has been set. It comes back as `undefined` so the `getSpec()` function does not run, and no spec is returned. So I am not sure what I am missing, or why it would still be `undefined` in my `SharedService` after it has been set. Should the shared service keep a reference to what was set? Or am I completely misunderstanding this concept?

I have also explored ways of sharing this data via promises/observables. However I have not had any luck with that either. And the majority of the examples I have found use HTTP, which I really do not need at this point.

**Update:**

Here is some more info.

**Boot.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    APP_BASE_HREF,
    Location,
    LocationStrategy,
    HashLocationStrategy,
    PathLocationStrategy
} from 'angular2/router';

import {AppComponent} from './components/app.component';
import {SharedService} from './services/shared.service';

bootstrap(<any>AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    SharedService,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: PathLocationStrategy})
]);
```

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {ComponentA} from './componentA';


@Component({
    selector   : 'body',
    directives : [ComponentA, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template   : `
        <app>
            <header>
                <component-a></component-a>
            </header>
            <div>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </app>
    `
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/:appName/', name: 'ComponentB', component: ComponentB}
])

export class AppComponent
{
    constructor(){}
}
```

**Update 2:**

Here is a plunker I created to try to isolate the issue. I removed the router stuff and simplified the whole thing. I am still seeing the same result..

https://plnkr.co/edit/kx6FWWGS1i04bH5J9DXM?p=preview

Watch the `console.log()`

**Fixed:**

This was the key.

> Be sure to remove configurations in the providers attribute of your
>   two components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your service isn't actually shared. I mean you could have two instances according to the way you configured providers.

To be sure, just add the service when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

Be sure to remove configurations in the `providers` attribute of your two components.

If you're interested in hierarchical injectors of Angular2 (the concept behind this), you could have a look at this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually have tried that also. Still no luck. I will give it another shot though just to be sure.

Comment: Could you add the configuration of your components? And the way you boostrap your application... Thanks!

Comment: Another thing could be to be sure when you update / get the value according to the hook methods you leverage (ngOnInit, ngDoCheck, ...)

Comment: Sure I will see if I can try to include a simplified version of that

Comment: Still no luck with adding the service to the bootstrap. I have updated my answer with some more context.

Comment: I created a plunker. I removed the router stuff from the equation and still have the same problem.. https://plnkr.co/edit/kx6FWWGS1i04bH5J9DXM?p=preview

Comment: K, got it working now.. This -> "Be sure to remove configurations in the providers attribute of your two components." was the key.