# Angular 2 event emitters?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

> Can I catch a event emitted from a leaf component only in the root
>   component? I didn't find any information about this.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can only be notified on a custom event from a child component in the parent component.

To implement your use case, you need to implement a shared service that you specify into your root component in its `providers` attribute. This way it will be shared with this component and all the graph of its children.

This service contains an observable / subject. When a leaf wants to trigger an event, it will leverage the observer associated with this observable or the subject. The root component subscribes on this observable / subject to be notified

Here is a sample implementation. First the service:

```
export class EventService {
  subject$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
}
```

Root component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ EventService ]
  (...)
})
export class RootComponent {
  constructor(private service:EventService) {
    this.eventService.subject$.subscribe(event => {
      // Execute when the event is received from leaf component
    });
  }
}
```

Leaf component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <div (click)="emitEventToRoot()">Emit event</div>
  `
})
export class LeafComponent {
  constructor(private service:EventService) {
  }

  emitEventToRoot() {
    // Send the event to the root component
    this.eventService.subject$.emit('some event');
  }
}
```

These links could interest you:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html