# When we use providers in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

Some of examples From angular 2 documents they used for http also

```
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS }    from '@angular/http';
import { HeroService }       from './hero.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-toh',
  template: `
  <hero-list></hero-list>
  `,
  directives: [HeroListComponent],
  providers:  [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    HeroService,
  ]
})
```

Comment: They are entry point to make dependencies available for component..

Answer (score 4):

Providers need to be used to provide a way to create instances to inject. For example, if you want to inject an `Http` instance you need to have define the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` (that contains the provider for the `Http` type.

An important thing to understand is that Angular2 supports hierarchical injectors for dependency injector. I mean an injector is associated with each component and the current injector is a child injector of the injector of the parent component.

This question could interest you:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: Thanks @Thierry !!! 
Can You please explain me (source: string, subString: string): boolean;

Comment: You're welcome! It's the TypeScript syntax for methods / functions. A method with two parameters (source of type string and subString of type string) that returns a boolean value.