# Angular2: Service with Model - "no provider for model"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

What I'm trying to do is create a service that uses a model to show an alert. The alert-model should be necessary nowhere else but in that service but I am not able to make this work. My service:

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from "angular2/core";
import {AlertModel} from "../models/alert.model";

@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
    constructor(@Inject(AlertModel) alertModel: AlertModel) {
    }

    public alert(){
        this.alertModel.message = 'success';
        //...
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): No provider for AlertModel! (UserComponent -> AlertService -> AlertModel)
```

I'm new to angular and I do not understand this. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the `AlertModel` somewhere

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [AlertModel])
```

or in the root component (preferred):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [AlertModel],
  ...
})
```

Ensure `AlertModel` has the `@Injectable()` decorator and all its constructor parameters are provided as well (if it has any)

`@Inject(AlertModel)` is redundant if the type of the constructor parameter is already `AlertModel`. `@Inject()` is only necessary if the type differs or if `AlertModel` doesn't have the `@Injectable()` decorator.

```
constructor(@Inject(AlertModel) alertModel: AlertModel) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error since there is no provider for the `AlertModel` class visible from the `UserComponent` component (that calls the service). You can define either this class in the `providers` attribute of the component either when bootstrapping your application.

See the question to know more about how hierarchical injectors works and how to inject things into services:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Since the `AlertModel` class seems to be a model class I don't think that you need to inject it. You can simply import the class and instantiate it:

```
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
  alertModel: AlertModel = new AlertModel();

  public alert(){
    this.alertModel.message = 'success';
    //...
  }
}
```