# No provider while using Injector in Angular 2

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

First of all, I have a `Context` class and a`Singleton`. 
I would like `Context` to give an instance of Http and Events to `Singleton`.

```
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
import { Injectable, Injector, Provider, provide } from 'angular2/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Context{
    constructor(private http: Http, private events: Events){}
}

export class Singleton{
    private static INSTANCE: Singleton;

    private context: Context;

    constructor(){
        if(Singleton.INSTANCE){
            throw new Error();
        }
        let injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
            Https,
            Events
        ])
        this.context = injector.get(Context);
    }

}
```

However, when I compile and inspect. An error with "No provider" was raised. Thus, how could I add a provider?

Secondly, how could I use http and events in `Singleton`? I suppose `this.http` in `Singleton` doesn't work.

Comment: Why is that "because it can't accept them in constructor."?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Well, it can accept. But I don't want to "new" stuff manually.

Comment: Then just inject `Context` to `Singleton`. See my updated answer. You need to provide `Context` and `Singleton` somewhere `@App({ ... , providers: [Singleton, Context]})`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `Context` as well:

```
let injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
        Https,
        Events,
        Context // <-------
    ])
    this.context = injector.get(Context);
}
```

That being said, Angular2 will keep a single instance per provider and you don't need to implicitly leverage the `Injector` class.

You don't need a SINGLETON class. You can inject directly a `Context` instance into another component or service:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ Context ]
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private context:Context) {
  }
}
```

By setting the provider in the `providers` attribute of a component, `context` will be a singleton for the component, its sub components and all services they will call.

If you want to define a singleton for the whole application, specify the provider when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(App, [ Context ]);
```

Don't forget to remove if from the `providers` attribute of components.

You also need to be aware that injectors are linked to components. For more details, this question you help you:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

**Edit**

To use the `Http` class into your `Singleton` class, you need to define the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` instead of the `Http` one:

```
let injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
        HTTP_PROVIDERS, // <-------
        Events,
        Context
    ])
    this.context = injector.get(Context);
    this.http = injector.get(Http); // <-------
}
```

Comment: Well, we use singleton at work. So in fact, it's not because I want to inject then I use singleton. It's I need to use singleton then I need to inject.

Comment: Plus, how can I use `http` in the class `Singleton`? Should I declare `http` and `events` as public in Context?

Comment: Just a small question: I've tried to use injector and it works. However, if I didn't make any mistake, the instance of `Events` is not the same as `Events` that passed by constructor. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

**update**

```
export class Singleton{
    private static INSTANCE: Singleton;

    constructor(private context:Context){
      console.log(context.http);
      console.log(context.events);
    }
}
```

**original**

```
    let injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
        Https,
        Events
    ])
```

creates a new and independent injector that only knows the providers `Https` and `Events.

You need to inject Angulars injector in order to be able to get instances from providers provided for example in `bootstrap(...)`

```
constructor(private injector:Injector){
  this.context = injector.get(Context);
}
```