# Passing data between two components

Tags: angular

I have two components , component1 and component2

component1 contains following piece of code

```
export class CpOne{
   passedValue:number=null;

   setValue(x){
     this.passedValue = x;
   }
}
```

the component two contains following piece of code

```
import { CpOne }   from './component1'

export class CpTwo{
     constructor(private cp : CpOne){}
}
```

what I want to achieve , is somehow invoke setValue method of component1 in component2 , or basically send data from component2 to component1 and store them in passedValue variable.

Is such a thing possible in angular2 without using templates and passing value with it?

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!%23parent-to-child-local-var

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal what if i have multiple componentes imported? How do i specify i want to send data so specific one

Answer (score 0):

The data share does not work in that way. To share data between components you could use:

```
- @ViewChild/@ViewChildren
- Services
- @Input
- Observables
```

Answer (score 0):

The global answer is to leverage a shared service and use it to communicate between components.

Most of the time, you need to define your shared service when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

and not defining it again within the `providers` attribute of your components. This way you will have a single instance of the service for the whole application.

You can implement the shared service like that:

```
export class SharedService {
  valueUpdated:Subject<any> = new Subject();

  updateData(data:any) {
    this.valueUpdated.next(data);
  }
}
```

To be notified, simply subscribe to the subject

```
constructor(private service:SharedService) {
  this.service.valueUpdated.subscribe(data => {
    // do something
  });
}
```

---

One component is a sub component of your `AppComponent` one, simply remove the `providers` attribute like this:

```
@Component({
  selector : "other",
  // providers : [SharedService], <----
  template : `
    I'm the other component. The shared data is: {{data}}
  `,
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit{
  (...)
}
```

This way they will shared the same instance of the service for both components. `OtherComponent` will use the one from the parent component (`AppComponent`).

This is because of the "hierarchical injectors" feature of Angular2. For more details, see this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

---

By injecting the parent into the child, you need to be careful about cyclic dependency (use `forwardRef` - see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/forwardRef-function.html). But it's possible to have something like that:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div (click)="onClick()">Click</div>
  `,
  (...)
})
export class CpTwo{
  constructor(private cp : CpOne){}

  onClick() {
    this.cp.setValue({ value: 'some value' });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that without using `@intput`/`@output`, I see two options:

- [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html): If `CpTwo` is a child of `CpOne`, you can inject `CpOne` into `CpTwo`
- [Communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service): `CpTwo` sets a service value, and `CpOne` access it. To do that you could use an `observable`.

Hope it helps.